# How to save a class inside a variable with setState with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to try to save a variable with a whole class imported from a different file. The variable is saved from the setState method inside the constructor of the actual class. The problem is, that it doesn't render anything at all. Here's a piece of the code:

```
import Timer from './App';

class Nuevo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            game: 1,
            timer: <Timer />
        }
    }
    setup = () => {
        return(
            this.state.timer
        );
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <span>{this.state.timer}</span>
        );
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `this.timer = <new Timer />;` outside of the `this.state` method, and it didn't work at all.
(The importation/exportation of `Timer` does work completely fine, since it's rendered before).

Here's what I'm trying to do.

The `game` variable changes between sections of the whole game. With 1 being the first of three. I'm using conditional rendering for this. The problem lies elsewhere whatsoever.

Class `Nuevo` is supposed to call `Timer` from the imports. Then, `Timer` gets saved in a variable, such as to not render a new class everytime I re-render the whole thing (since I have it divided by sections, whenever the section is changed, `Timer` renders anew, when I only want to view `Timer` as it was before).

Thanks for helping!

If something's not understood from my sample, ask, hope it's not confusing.

Also, I've considered changing the whole code, so as to merge both classes, but I really want to learn if what I ask is possible at all, and if it is possible, how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never do this. You should always return your components and eventually render them out in the render method of the class.

You can manage conditional rendering of your component:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.

You can manage the state using the available lifecycle methods, which can listen to updates in your application:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

If you can't reach what you are trying to achieve with the above documentation, I would like to know: what are you trying to do more specifically and why?

Comment: I don't think this is gonna help me, since I ask here on stackoverflow because those tutorials don't really help much.
What I mean to do is to render `Timer` as much as I want, without resetting what goes on in it.

Comment: If you wish to "render" the <Timer /> component as much as you want. You can achieve this by what I said above. You simply render your component in the render() method, then by provoking an action like an onClick event (or anything else) you can update the state, check for the state to be updated with the state lifecycle methods mentioned above, and then your <Timer /> will re-render. The way you are doing it now, is simply not the "React way" of doing things. Don't get me wrong: you're not really giving us an answer on "why" you want to do it like this instead of the "React way".

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not a big fan of a `you should not do this and that, blablabla...` answers, heres example of how you could achieve your desired result. https://codesandbox.io/s/nkx3lpp3rl

> If solution is with in languages features and it fits to an problem better than others, I do not see why you should not use it even if it dosen't satisfy some of the `best practices` community fellows. Just make sure if you are working with a larger team that this solution is suitable for others members.

**Background of an answer**

Basically solution is to use `React.cloneElement`-method from `React.js`. [read more about React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

Below is demonstration that if you save your `component` to state as `JSX`you should use it as `variable` in `cloneElement`-method and otherwise if you saved it to state as `variable` use it's `JSX` counter part inside method.

**apply `component` as `JSX`**

```
  // Initialize state object
  state = {
    timer: <Timer />
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">{React.cloneElement(this.state.timer, {})}</div>
    );
  }
```

**apply `component` as `variable`**

```
  // Initialize state object
  state = {
    timer: Timer
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">{React.cloneElement(<this.state.timer />, {})}</div>
    );
  }
```